# @media queries not working in the signature

Tags: html, css, media

My signature is composed of 3 simple images. I am trying to make it responsive but cannot get it working even on a desktop when making the browser smaller let along a mobile device.

I looked at a few examples but seem to be overlooking something. What I want to achieve is, when viewed on a desktop the signature is 40% of the original width, and when viewed on a small screen it is 100%.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Signature</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type"text/css" media="screen">
    /*Global Styles*/
    table[class="sig"] img {
            width: 40% !important;
            height: auto !important;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
        table[class="sig"] img {
            width: 100% !important;
            height: auto !important;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="sig" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><img src="http://example.com/main.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://example.com/left.png"></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/right.png"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think it is working fine - are looking for something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/mBbRaK

Answer (score 0):

Try these CSS Selectors instead:

```
table.sig img {
  width: 40% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  table.sig img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }
}
```

**[Working Resizable Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1eu8frtx/1/)** (used placehold.it images for demo)

- Also remember to close your `<a></a>` tag.